# What the best way to creat Expandable Recyclerview Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Please tell me how can I create Expandable Recyclerview with Groups items and his Childs items. Now i am searching for the best way to creat expandable recyclerview, because i have tried AnimatedExpandableListView librari and i found some bugs.

I will be very grateful if you show me some examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.github.cachapa:ExpandableLayout:2.9.2'
```

try this I'm using this library currently inside the app that I'm working on, it's simple easy to use and works fine, let me know if you try it !!

Comment: Maybe there is some better way without using libraries?

Comment: I think libraries work as an invented wheel you know so why invent wheel again when it's already there, that's only my opinion but if you still wanna use any manual approach I can try referring you to something like that

Comment: https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/ give this link a try

Comment: https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout - I looked at this library and did not see in the example group with many childs. I see only example with one group with one child. But i need groups with many childs.

Comment: Your question is still not clear if you can elaborate it or atleast give it a rough visual representation

Comment: https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/ - I want  like here. I open one element from the list, several nested ones appear.

Comment: There are a lot of libraries and unfortunately I don't know which ones have bugs and which don't. As i mentioned in the question i used AnimatedExpandableListView  for creat expandable recyclerview, but  i fond bug. When i use animation on AnimatedExpandableListView  component to change it height size, i see that animation is laging.

Comment: And don't get me wrong, I'm now looking for the best way to create Expandable Recyclerview without trying all the libraries that exist. if I try all the libraries, I will waste a lot of time. So I thought maybe there is a better way to create Expandable Recyclerview  for myself. Or if not and i must use libs , i try to find the best library without bugs.

Comment: i'm telling you the library about is bug free till now and i'm using it in my official app that i'm working on right now, so this library enables you to achieve thing that you want to
All you have to do is add expandable layout and inside that layout add a text view which shows text header now add click listener on the layout and on expand decide whatever you wanna show in it. do the same approach for other childs too, let me know if you don't get me

Comment: implementation 'com.github.cachapa:ExpandableLayout:2.9.2' - i see group element with one child element in example gif . Is it posible added more then one child element?

Comment: please elaborate your question and try to be clear

Comment: https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout -  I opened lib that you advised me in github. And i see in example  that when user click on a group element, it opens one chield element (subtitle  "RecyclerView items", it is gif 3 from above) . Is it possible to show user more than one chield element in this opened group element ?

Comment: yes obviously u can add more than one child element, that gif on github site was just for an example to show how it would really look like

Comment: Okey, thank u very much! I answered your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

that's how I'm using it in my application this card view is inside a recycler view and there's another recycler view inside this card view which I'm expanding and collapsing on arrow image click
[when layout is collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3N3.png)

[when layout is expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRxbM.png)

Comment: Can you show example code?
I found some example code like here , but i got bug. I explain it in this issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472390/i-trying-to-do-expandable-recyclerview-but-have-a-bug-android-java