# I trying to do Expandable Recyclerview but have a bug Android/Java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I try to implement expandable RecyclerView as shown in this example :
https://github.com/CodingSTUFF070/Nested-RecyclerView-Inside-Expandable-RecyclerView

But I have bug :
When I implement the same for my app. Steps to reproduce - Click 1st item (Instant Food and Noodles) and scroll to last and click last item (Personal Care) without closing 1st opened item. Now, if you scroll-up and see the child items of 1st parent, you'll see child items of lastly opened parent (Personal Care).

Please tell me how to fix this?

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<DataModel> mList;
private ItemAdapter adapter;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recyclervie);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mList = new ArrayList<>();

    //list1
    List<String> nestedList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList1.add("Jams and Honey");
    nestedList1.add("Pickles and Chutneys");
    nestedList1.add("Readymade Meals");
    nestedList1.add("Chyawanprash and Health Foods");
    nestedList1.add("Pasta and Soups");
    nestedList1.add("Sauces and Ketchup");
    nestedList1.add("Namkeen and Snacks");
    nestedList1.add("Honey and Spreads");

    List<String> nestedList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList2.add("Book");
    nestedList2.add("Pen");
    nestedList2.add("Office Chair");
    nestedList2.add("Pencil");
    nestedList2.add("Eraser");
    nestedList2.add("NoteBook");
    nestedList2.add("Map");
    nestedList2.add("Office Table");

    List<String> nestedList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList3.add("Decorates");
    nestedList3.add("Tea Table");
    nestedList3.add("Wall Paint");
    nestedList3.add("Furniture");
    nestedList3.add("Bedsits");
    nestedList3.add("Certain");
    nestedList3.add("Namkeen and Snacks");
    nestedList3.add("Honey and Spreads");

    List<String> nestedList4 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList4.add("Pasta");
    nestedList4.add("Spices");
    nestedList4.add("Salt");
    nestedList4.add("Chyawanprash");
    nestedList4.add("Maggie");
    nestedList4.add("Sauces and Ketchup");
    nestedList4.add("Snacks");
    nestedList4.add("Kurkure");

    List<String> nestedList5 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList5.add("Jams and Honey");
    nestedList5.add("Pickles and Chutneys");
    nestedList5.add("Readymade Meals");
    nestedList5.add("Chyawanprash and Health Foods");
    nestedList5.add("Pasta and Soups");
    nestedList5.add("Sauces and Ketchup");
    nestedList5.add("Namkeen and Snacks");
    nestedList5.add("Honey and Spreads");

    List<String> nestedList6 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList6.add("Pasta");
    nestedList6.add("Spices");
    nestedList6.add("Salt");
    nestedList6.add("Chyawanprash");
    nestedList6.add("Maggie");
    nestedList6.add("Sauces and Ketchup");
    nestedList6.add("Snacks");
    nestedList6.add("Kurkure");


    List<String> nestedList7 = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList7.add("Decorates");
    nestedList7.add("Tea Table");
    nestedList7.add("Wall Paint");
    nestedList7.add("Furniture");
    nestedList7.add("Bedsits");
    nestedList7.add("Certain");
    nestedList7.add("Namkeen and Snacks");
    nestedList7.add("Honey and Spreads");

    mList.add(new DataModel(nestedList1 , "Instant Food and Noodles"));
    mList.add(new DataModel( nestedList2,"Stationary"));
    mList.add(new DataModel( nestedList3,"Home Care"));
    mList.add(new DataModel(nestedList4 ,"Grocery & Staples"));
    mList.add(new DataModel(nestedList5,"Pet Care"));
    mList.add(new DataModel(nestedList6,"Baby Care"));
    mList.add(new DataModel(nestedList7 ,"Personal Care"));

    adapter = new ItemAdapter(mList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

**DataModel:**

```
public class DataModel {

private List<String> nestedList;
private String itemText;
private boolean isExpandable;

public DataModel(List<String> itemList, String itemText) {
    this.nestedList = itemList;
    this.itemText = itemText;
    isExpandable = false;
}

public void setExpandable(boolean expandable) {
    isExpandable = expandable;
}

public List<String> getNestedList() {
    return nestedList;
}

public String getItemText() {
    return itemText;
}

public boolean isExpandable() {
    return isExpandable;
}
```

}

**ItemAdapter:**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

private List<DataModel> mList;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public ItemAdapter(List<DataModel> mList){
    this.mList  = mList;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.each_item , parent , false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    DataModel model = mList.get(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(model.getItemText());

    boolean isExpandable = model.isExpandable();
    holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    if (isExpandable){
        holder.mArrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
    }else{
        holder.mArrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
    }

    NestedAdapter adapter = new NestedAdapter(list);
    holder.nestedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.getContext()));
    holder.nestedRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.nestedRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            model.setExpandable(!model.isExpandable());
            list = model.getNestedList();
            notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private RelativeLayout expandableLayout;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private ImageView mArrowImage;
    private RecyclerView nestedRecyclerView;


    public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTv);
        mArrowImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arro_imageview);
        nestedRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_rv);
    }
}
```

}

**NestedAdapter:**

```
public class NestedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NestedAdapter.NestedViewHolder> {

private List<String> mList;

public NestedAdapter(List<String> mList){
    this.mList = mList;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public NestedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nested_item , parent , false);
    return new NestedViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NestedViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTv.setText(mList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class NestedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView mTv;
    public NestedViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nestedItemTv);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the code here in the question as a [mcve]. Links can break, or the linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for others with the same problem. See [ask].

Comment: I edited question as you said.